# Iterate over a specific directory level

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to iterate over directories that match this structure:

```
../../SOURCE/SOURCE_A/sourceFiles_A/
../../SOURCE/SOURCE_B/sourceFiles_B/
../../SOURCE/SOURCE_C/sourceFiles_C/
../../SOURCE/SOURCE_D/sourceFiles_D/
```

I'm trying it with:

```
Dir['../../SOURCE/SOURCE_*/**/*'].each do |dir|
  ...
end
```

It goes recursively through sub-directories of `sourceFilesA`, `sourceFilesB`, etc. I would like to iterate only through the levels `sourceFilesA`, `sourceFilesB`, etc. How can I do this?

Comment: so for `../../SOURCE/SOURCE_A/sourceFiles_A/` you want the file to be located at `../../SOURCE/SOURCE_A/myFile.txt` ?

Comment: No, on this level: ../../SOURCE/SOURCE_A/sourceFiles_A/myFile.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it without the `**/` (include sub-directories)? The `/` at the end takes only folders, not files.

```
Dir['../../SOURCE/SOURCE_*/*/'].each do |dir|
  ...
end
```